# Weird Screen display after coming from sleep mode

Tags: display

After Resuming my system after sleep mode,display shows overlapping of multiple pages.Initially it shows black screen after that when I try to switch to different tab it shows partial display of previous tabs as well.
This issue is also happening with Slack and other software as well.